# Keyboard and mouse not working in Windows 8.1 after booting

Tags: keyboard, mouse, windows-8.1

I recently installed Windows 8.1 Pro. The only driver I installed was the chipset driver for my motherboard ASUS P8Z68-V PRO/GEN3.

When I start my PC, keyboard and mouse are responding in BIOS. But when Windows shows welcome screen, keyboard and mouse are not working. Shutdown + power on **doesn't** help. Pressing reset button **DOES** help. I have logitech wireless keyboard+mouse set.

It's very frustrating that I have to reset my PC every morning when I start it.

Anyone familiar with this behavior?

**UPDATE:**

- I have Windows 8.1 driver from ASUS support page.
- The same behavior exists even if I don't install any drivers after clean install.

Comment: I would remove the chipset and see if it helps. I am going to guess you install a version that does not support Windows 8.1 ASUS is slow in that regard even for its **current** flagship products.  I have found that Windows 8.1 and Windows 8.0 drivers are not compatible with one another.

Comment: Thanks for reply, on ASUS support page I found Windows 8.1 drivers for my motherboard, so I have a valid driver (I updated the question above).

Comment: Your keyboard and mouse PS2 or USB?

Comment: USB. One wireless receiver for both mouse & keyboard.

Comment: Have you tried a different USB port?

Comment: I did try different ports, I doubt it's a USB issue. I will check my BIOS version and try to update it. Will see if it helps.

Comment: Seems like it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be issues with Windows 8.1 and ASUS motherboards. 
Links:

[Help! After installing Windows 8.1, the SuperSpeed ports of my ASUS system don’t work…](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/usbcoreblog/archive/2013/10/19/help-after-installing-windows-8-1-the-superspeed-ports-of-my-asus-system-don-t-work.aspx).

[Unable to use USB ports since upgrading to Windows 8.1 Preview](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/hardware/unable-to-use-usb-ports-since-upgrading-to-windows/17feadaf-d9bf-41b3-be28-f663dcbf73a5)

I had a similar problem as the OP and updating the BIOS solved it for me.